# Inject additional logic when elastic searches based on search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a scenario where i need to extend search behavior and add some additional filter logic based on the document id . If the document can be visible to the user searching and then show in search result but have not found any.

Currently as part of search , search query is executed after applying all the filters. After the search results are fetched, we need to know if the resource can be shown to this user. Pretty much like ACL.

Now, if i apply these authorization/ audience type filters myself after getting results from elastic search , it creates a lot of problems like the aggregations count changes post filter. Also, the pagination of results gets impacted.

Is a there a way to implement such rules as hook provided by elastic search. That is if i can implement some logic implementing some interface and then call some web service returning a boolean and then adding the search result to the final collection based on that.

Some insight would be very useful.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution around this .